# Is there a reason why large JSON files (4000 objects) don't write to dynamodb but small files (10 objects) works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

Getting a `Task timed out after 3.01 seconds` message in cloudwatch when trying to read `large JSON(66mb)` from `S3 bucket` and write data to dynamodb.

Smaller JSON files are reading and writing to my dynamodb table but when the JSON file contains a larger amount of objects (4000 objects, 66MB file) in this instance, the lambda function just returns `Task timed out after 3.01 seconds`.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient( {
    convertEmptyValues: true
} );


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const{name} = event.Records[0].s3.bucket;
    const{key} = event.Records[0].s3.object;

    const params = {
        Bucket: name,
        Key: key
    }

    try {
    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const carsStr = data.Body.toString();
    const usersJSON = JSON.parse(carsStr);
    console.log(`USERS ::: ${carsStr}`);

     for (var i = 0; i < usersJSON.length; i++) {
             var record = usersJSON[i];
              console.log("Inserting record: " + record);

            var putParams = {
                Item: record,
                ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
                TableName: "cars"
            };

            await documentClient.put(putParams).promise();
            }


    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

};
```

Comment: This issue is related to the lambda,What's the lambda timeout?

Comment: Also consider using the DocumentClient's batchWrite method.

Comment: The problem was the lambda timeout! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda default timeout is 3 seconds and that is the reason you see a timeout error in the logs. You can increase it as per your need and up to a maximum of 900 seconds

As per [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)

> Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run
>   before stopping it. The default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed
>   value is 900 seconds.

**Note:** Increasing timeout is surely a solution for task that requires longer execution time. But always consider code optimization before increasing the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Lambda to write to DynamoDB, populate your table on your development machine.

If you are expecting large JSON files coming into your S3 bucket often, to trigger the Lambda, you need to increase the default timeout of your function. The maximum timeout is 15 minutes. The default timeout is 3 seconds.

You can also increase the number of DynamoDB Write Capacity Units on your table. A write capacity unit represents one write per second, for an item up to 1 KB in size. For example, suppose that you create a table with 10 write capacity units. This allows you to perform 10 writes per second, for items up to 1 KB in size per second.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Write